# Linear sum assignment/Hungarian method performance in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, assignment-problem

I need to speed up a process of finding most optimal distance for each entry. I am using `gower.dist` from `StatMatch` and `solve_LSAP` from the `clue` package. The gower distance takes no time at all, however the LSAP solver takes too long with the number of times I need to run it.

Is there a way to make this run faster using parallel computing or just making part of it run in parallel [[link to clue github]](https://github.com/cran/clue/blob/master/R/lsap.R) [[link to scientific journal discussing this]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S016781911630045X) or another solver that I may be unaware of that is faster? The other two libraries I am aware of are `adagio` and `RcppHungarian` (both are slower).

Example data:
[Gower Distance Data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uieSAfvYkEAlXnwr3k9DQqtOkwNcZ1fd?usp=sharing) (google drive link to folder with data)

```
> dim(gowerdist)
[1]  4309 10366
```

```
solve_LSAP(gowerdist, maximum = FALSE)
```

Comment: I use `solve_LSAP()` on a very similar sized problem and it runs in well under a second. How long is it running for you?

Comment: Wow. 8-10 min for me. So running it 4-5 times takes like 40-50 min. I have 32 gb of ram and Intel core i7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clue::solve_LSAP` uses the Hungarian algorithm.  The Jonker and Volgenant (1987) algorithm, implemented in [`TreeDist::LAPJV()`](https://ms609.github.io/TreeDist/reference/LAPJV.html), is more efficient.

I tested a reduced version of the matrix to get results in seconds rather than minutes; differences in run time are likely to increase with larger matrices.

```r
gower <- read.csv("GowerDistance.csv")
dim(gower)
gowerMat <- as.matrix(gower)
gow1 <- gowerMat[1:2400, 1:4800]
```

```r
tictoc::tic()
clue <- clue::solve_LSAP(gow1, maximum = FALSE)
tictoc::toc()
# 67.95 sec elapsed
```

```r
tictoc::tic()
td <- TreeDist::LAPJV(gow1)
tictoc::toc()
# 20.24 sec elapsed
```

`GraphAlignment::LinearAssignment()` [on Bioconductor](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GraphAlignment.html) also uses the LAPJV algorithm, but can only be applied to square matrices.  (A workaround is to add extra rows to the matrix with extremely high values.)

Another alternative is [lpSolve](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=lpSolve); this does not specify which algorithm it uses, but is much slower

```r
tictoc::tic()
lps <- lpSolve::lp.assign(gowerMat[1:800, 1:1600]) # much smaller matrix
tictoc::toc()
# 364.67 sec elapsed
```

Comment: amazing thank you i just implemented this into my code

Answer (score 0):

If you can transform your problem to run on integers instead of doubles, it should be much faster. Not sure how practical it is for all use cases, but that may be an option. Still not blazing fast, but definitely an improvement.

```r
gowerdist_all <- readr::read_csv("GowerDistance.csv")

gowerdist1 <- as.matrix(gowerdist_all[,-1])

gowerdist2 <- as.matrix(gowerdist_all[,-1]) * 10000
mode(gowerdist2) <- "integer"
```

This takes 548 seconds.

```r
tictoc::tic()
z <- clue::solve_LSAP(gowerdist1, maximum = FALSE)
tictoc::toc()
# 547.92 sec elapsed
```

Rounded as an integer takes 116 seconds.

```r
tictoc::tic()
z <- clue::solve_LSAP(gowerdist2, maximum = FALSE)
tictoc::toc()
# 115.64 sec elapsed
```

Comment: Unfortunately these lead to slightly different answers. But intriguing and maybe I can try to do something with this new information such as ranking the row values and then running LSAP?

Comment: Yeah, the answers would be slightly different. But depending on what you are doing, it could either be critical or in the noise. It is *a* way, but like I said, may not be suitable for applications. Good luck!